# JavaScript: Intercepting form submit and identifying which form made the submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I am trying to intercept form submits from webpages I dont control.

My current implementation is ...

```
// During onLoad, loop through all forms and for each form object
var prevonsubmit = formobj.onsubmit;
if (prevonsubmit) {
    formobj.onsubmit = function f() {
        if(prevonsubmit()) {
            interceptform();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
} else {
    formobj.onsubmit = function ff() {
        interceptform();
        return true;
    };
}
```

The problem with this is, inside interceptform(), I am unable to identify which form actually made this submission. Is there a way I actually get the form object that is trying to submit? Keep in mind that some of the forms I see do not have a name or id specified and there is more than one form (in the same webpage) with same action.

Edit:
The purpose is capture the content in the input tags that belong to the form.
A made up example of what I see in a form:

```
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/html/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
</form>
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/html/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="l"/>
</form>
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/html/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="l"/>
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
</form>
```

Edit2:

Based on @ruakh answer, the solution I ended up using:

```
var prevonsubmit = formobj.onsubmit;
if (prevonsubmit) 
    formobj.onsubmit = createOnSubmitFunctionWithOld(prevonsubmit, formobj);
else
    formobj.onsubmit = createOnSubmitFunction(formobj);

// Definition of the functions:
function createOnSubmitFunctionWithOld(prevonsubmit,formObj) {
    return function () {
        if (prevonsubmit()) {
            interceptform(formObj);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
}
function createOnSubmitFunction(formObj) {
    return function () {
        interceptform(formObj);
        return true;
    };
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of determining which form is submitted? And can you post and example of the forms on a page so we can see what youre dealing with?

Comment: @prodigitalson, the purpose is to capture text from the submission. I added the purpose and an example of forms I see to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass `formobj` as an argument to `interceptform()`:

```
        interceptform(formobj);
```

But bear in mind that both with `formobj` and with `prevonsubmit`, you have to be careful to avoid capturing a variable you don't want to. For example, in JavaScript, this:

```
var functions = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    { functions[i] = function() { return i; }; }
```

creates ten functions that all return `10`, because they all capture the same `i` variable that's been incremented up to `10` by the time the functions are ever called. In the above example, you could write something like:

```
function new_constant_function(return_value)
    { return function() { return return_value; }; }

// ...

var functions = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    { functions[i] = new_constant_function(i); }
```

to copy each value of `i` into a new local variable `return_value` whose value never changes; or, a bit more tersely, this:

```
var functions = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    { functions[i] = (function(_i){ return function(){ return _i; } })(i); }
```

You'll almost certainly need to do something similar in your case. (But without seeing a bit more of the context of your code, it's hard to say exactly what.)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I looking for. I tried the same, by passing as an argument, but some how did not realize there was a bug in my current code. The solution I ended up with, if anyones is interested is... 

var prevonsubmit = formobj.onsubmit;
if (prevonsubmit) 
    formobj.onsubmit = 
else
    formobj.onsubmit =

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop through document.forms and append a hidden field to each one, or assign an id to the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loopoing over the forms from a function, then:

```
> var prevonsubmit = formobj.onsubmit;
> if (prevonsubmit) {
>      formobj.onsubmit = function f() {
>          if(prevonsubmit()) {
```

*prevonsubmit* has a closure to the outer variable, it will reference the **last** value of prevonsubmit, so they will all reference the same function. This may "work", but will fail if any of your forms has a current listener that is different to any other form.

```
>              interceptform();
```

You can simply pass *this* from the function to *interceptform*:

```
               interceptform(this);
```

and *interceptform* will be passed a reference to the element calling the function (presumably the form being submitted).

```
>              return true;
>          }
>          return false;
```

That will (probably) cancel submission of any form that doesn't have an existing listener. Is that what you want?

```
>      };
>  } else {
>      formobj.onsubmit = function ff() {
```

Named function expressions are known to be buggy in at least one widely used browser. If you don't need a name (and it doesn't seem to be used here for anything), dont' use one. Keep the function anonymous.

```
>          interceptform();
>          return true;
>      };
>  }
```

Comment: I just understood how JS Closure works, and added a wrapper to make it work. And about the returning false, yes that was the intention, my function should return a false, with out intercepting the form, if the original onSubmit returns a false. I renamed the named function expressions into anonymous ones. Thanks for the comments and response. It was really helpful.